# Hyphenation: is it a "no-obligation quote" or a "no obligation quote"?

Tags: grammar, hyphenation

Should you give someone a "free, no-obligation quote" or a "free, no obligation quote"?

I'm unable to find concrete examples on any authoritative source either way.

Comment: Use the hyphen if you have say it. But really, what quote comes with an obligation? I always think "Without mentioning the free quote, would I have been obligated? No, I would not." I grant you the words are standard, but you are frightening your customer.